# Calculating custom metrics with tf.estimator.DNNRegressor in TensorFlow 1.10

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

How to configure a `tf.estimator.DNNRegressor` to report different metrics like **RMSE** and **MAE** while evaluating?

(One can ask the same question for `tf.estimator.DNNClassifier` and **AUC** metric)

> **Note:** I know that it must be done in `tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec` of
>   `model_fn()` for a custom `tf.estimator.Estimator`, but I don't know how to apply it for a
>   `tf.estimator.DNNRegressor`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [tf.contrib.estimator.add_metrics](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/estimator/add_metrics)